# MB Pro instantly gobbling up 70+ Gb SSD - How to track culprit?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ms-office, utilities

Mac OS 10.10.5, MB Pro 16 GB DDR, 500 Gb SSD.

Probable culprit app MS Excel for Mac 2011?

It seems that when I open up a spreadsheet with **lots** of formulas, within a few minutes I'm getting "Out of Disk Space" warnings. (before starting I have about 66 GB space)

How can I **verify** Excel is the culprit, and how can I manage it, other than buying a (very high priced) bigger SSD? I do keep my trash emptied, usually.

Are there any tools/utilities which show files accessed sorted by bytes-written first, then date?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the operating system is swapping out.

Open Activity Monitor from the Utilities folder (inside Applications) and select the Memory tab.  Click on the `Memory` category until the little caret arrow points downward.  Then open Excel.

At the bottom, you can see if `Swap Used` increases.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Answer (score 0):

To find the culprit, you can use a free application called [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/). Hope this helps!